# Find name of current wifi network on Windows

Tags: python, windows, wifi, ssid

I'd like to be able to determine the name of the current WiFi network using python. Subprocesses are acceptable. One mac, I'm able to do (in a subprocess)

```
networksetup -getairportnetwork en1
```

On windows, I haven't been able to find anything that works. The information doesn't seem to be in the output from `ipconfig`. I've also tried

```
netsh show wlan profiles name=*
```

but it gives the following error message:

```
The following command was not found: show wlan profiles name=*.
```

**EDIT**

So I had the parameter order backwards, should have been

```
netsh wlan show profiles name=*
```

This works, but only when I'm online. When I'm offline or connected to an ad-hoc network that doesn't provide internet access, I get the name of the most recently connected WiFi network.

Unfortunately, I'm going to be using this on ad-hoc networks in areas where I can't depend on an internet connection.

Answer (score 6):

To get the name of current profile you're connected to, try-

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

and see the last line. The Profile name you're connected to will be visible. In case, you're disconnected, this field will not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`netsh wlan show profiles name=*`

Comment: That works when I'm online, but not for ad-hoc networks (which is really what I'm after). When I'm on an ad-hoc network, I just get the name of the most recent SSID that provided internet connectivity.

Comment: For me this printed a list of every network I have ever connected to. How can I tell if one is currently available?

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Akshayanti's post, using python to get the name of the network specifically (the ESSID)

You can do this:

```
out = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show interfaces').decode("utf-8")
current = out.split("\n")[19].split(": ")[1]
print(f"Current WiFi Network: {current}")
```

You could condense this down further. But in essence, this is what you need to do.